# How to enable PowerPoint virtual laser pointer without holding CTRL key?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

How could I use [MS PowerPoints's virtual laser pointer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/turn-your-mouse-into-a-laser-pointer-HA101794344.aspx) without having to hold the CTRL key? When I'm doing a presentation I'm not near my keyboard, it would be great if I could show the virtual pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The below only applies to PowerPoint 2013:**

It's not very slick, but you can right-click your presentation while prsenting, and from the pop-up menu choose Pointer Options > Laser Pointer. Press ESC to go back to normal pointer.

If you haven't already set it up to use CTRL, another keyboard alternative is to press CTRL L during the presentation, though I know you were after a non-keyboard solution.

Comment: Hm... I can't seem to find it. This is the stuff I see http://screencast.com/t/Wm52YZeSt. I'm using PowerPoint 2010.

Comment: Apologies - I had 2013 open where this has now been promoted to this menu. I'll amend my answer to show. Can't see any better options for 2010.

Comment: no problem. I'm happy they have fixed this feature in PowerPoint 2013. Looking at some reviews it looks like the new version is a beautiful product!

Comment: Would be a great 3rd party tool :)